# Is a pseudometric $d(\cdot,x)$ continuous for fixed $x$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, continuity, metric-spaces

Let $(A,d)$ be a pseudometric space with semimetric $d$ defined by :

> **Def**. $d$ is a pseudometric on some space $A$ as soon as:
>
> 1. $\forall x\in A, d(x,x)=0$;
> 2. $\forall (x,y,z)\in A\times A\times A, d(x,y)\leq d(x,z)+d(z,y)$.
> 3. $d(x,y)=d(y,x)\geq 0, \forall x,y\in A (Scott's appointment)$.

**Question**. If $x\in A$ is fixed, is $d(\cdot,x): A\to\mathbb R$ a continuous function?

**My Attempt**

The topology can be determined by sequences in $(A,d)$.

One can prove that

$d(\cdot,x):A\to\mathbb R$ is continuous at $y\in A$ iff
$\lvert d(y,x)- d(y_n,x)\rvert \to 0$ for any sequence such that $d(y_n,y)\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$.

So take any sequence $y_n$ so that $y_n\to y$.
Let $\epsilon>0$. Then there will be $n_0:\forall n>n_0: d(y,y_n)<\epsilon$. Hence

(1) $ d(y_n,x)\leq d(y_n,y)+d(y,x)=d(x,y)+\epsilon$.

On the other hand,

(2) $ d(x,y)\leq d(x,y_n)+d(y_n,y)\leq d(x,y_n)+\epsilon$.

Combining $(1)-(2)$, we have $\epsilon-d(y_n,x)\leq d(x,y)\leq d(y_n,x)+\epsilon$. So $\lvert d(y,x)-d(y_n,x)\rvert\to 0$, which shows that $d(\cdot,x)$ is continuous at $y$.

I still have some doubts: (Q1) Is there any other way to show the result more directly? (Q2) Implicitly in this proof, did I use the topology on $(A,d)$ induced by $d$ and the topology on $(\mathbb R, \lvert\cdot,\cdot\rvert)$ induced by $\lvert\cdot,\cdot,\rvert$?

Comment: That is not the definition of a semimetric. If you added the requirements that $d(y,x)=d(x,y)\ge 0$ for all $x,y\in A$, you’d have a pseudoquasimetric. A semimetric satisfies your first requirement and the requirements that I just mentioned, but not the triangle inequality.

Comment: For continuity you need to define a topology on $A$. The usual topology induced by metrics and similar constructions has $B_r(x):=\{ y\in A \mid d(x,y)<r\}$ where $x\in A$ and $r\in \Bbb R$ as a basis of open sets. With this definition the semi-metric (or whatever it is) will be continuous wrt the topology it defines.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott yes, the author called that a semi-metric. Can you take a look at my argument above?

Comment: @CelineHarumi: Like **s.harp** I have to ask: what is the topology on $A$? Until we know that, the question is impossible to answer.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott My problem is that I want to show that $d(X_i,x)$ is a random variable where $X_i: (\Omega, \mathcal F)\to (A, \mathcal A)$  with $\mathcal A$ being a sigma-algebra spanned by the open sets for the semi-metric $d$. If I show $d(\cdot,x):A\to \mathbb R$ is continuous, I can argue that the composition $d(\cdot,x)\circ X_i$ is $\mathcal F-\mathcal B_{\mathbb R}$ measurable. That said, I believe that I can take the topology induced by $d$. What do you think?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Answering the question, I considered the topology on $(A,d)$ induced by $d$; that is, the topology of all open sets of $A$ for $d$.

Answer (score 1):

The topology on $A$ is the one generated by $d$ itself, say $\tau_d$. You are basically trying to show that the function $f_x:A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f_x(y)=d(y,x)$ is continuous on $A$ with respect to $\tau_d$.

Suppose $(X,d)$ and $(Y,s)$ are pseudometric spaces, then $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is continuous at $a \in X$ iff $f(x_n) \xrightarrow{s} f(a)$ for every sequence $x_n \xrightarrow{d} a$.

So I think your approach is quite good. Just in (1) the $=$ should be $\leq$ and in the second last paragraph it should be $d(y_n,x)-\epsilon \leq \cdots$.

You are using the topology on $(A,d)$ when you are talking about the convergence of $\{y_n\}_n$ and using the usual topology of $\mathbb{R}$ while talking about the convergence of the sequence $\{d(y_n,x)\}_n$. Here note that every metric is a pseudometric, so $|\cdot|$ on $\mathbb{R}$ is kind of treated as a pseudometric here.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I  think that for a rigorous proof, I need to show that (i) $(X,d)$ is first countable (which is the case), and (ii) that $d(\cdot,x)$ is sequentially continous (showed above). Then $d(\cdot,x)$ is continuous.

Comment: Well, first countability is obvious by considering $\{B(x,r): r ~\textit{is a positive rational number}\}$. Secondly if you know the definition of continuity of  $f:(X,d) \rightarrow (Y,s)$,  the lemma I stated in  the second paragraph can be easily proved. Also see carefully you only need to prove one thing between first countability  and the lemma that I stated.

Comment: When one says that $(X,d)$ is first countable, he is actually saying that $(X,\tau)$ is frist countable, where $\tau$ is the topology induced by $d$, right? The definition of first countability is for topological spaces.

Comment: Yes. What are the basic open sets of $(X, \tau)$ here? From that using definitions of open sets, neighborhood it is shown.